# The graph is not equal on the basis of the addition code in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I built a code to be displayed in a bar graph http://jsfiddle.net/KyDkq/

Now I modified the code in order to have a result according to my needs, and then making an array upstream, from which I pull out the data with which I create the chart. From here I elaborate the "date" of the graph, and then the "series" of the same:

```
for (i = 0; i < Sosta.length; i++) {
            if ((Sosta[i].DataInizio < InzioControllo) && (Sosta[i].DataFine > FineControllo)) {
            data[j] = {
                y: parseFloat(24.00).toFixed(2),
                color: colors[0]
            };
            j += 1;
        } else {
            if (Sosta[i].DataInizio > InzioControllo)
                data[j] = {
                    y: parseFloat(parseFloat(Sosta[i].DataInizio.substring(11, 13)) + Sosta[i].DataInizio.substring(14, 16) / 60 + Sosta[i].DataInizio.substring(17, 19) / 60 / 60).toFixed(2),
                    color: colors[1]
                };
            else
                data[j] = {
                    y: parseFloat(0.00).toFixed(2),
                    color: colors[1]
                };

            if (Sosta[i].DataFine < FineControllo)
                data[j+1] = {
                    y: parseFloat(parseFloat(Sosta[i].DataFine.substring(11, 13)) + Sosta[i].DataFine.substring(14, 16) / 60 + Sosta[i].DataFine.substring(17, 19) / 60 / 60).toFixed(2),
                    color: colors[0]
                };
            else
                data[j + 1] = {
                    y: parseFloat(24.00).toFixed(2),
                    color: colors[0]
                };
            j += 2;
        }

    }



var len = data.length-1,
    series = [],
    i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        series.push({ name: "", data: data[i] });
    }
```

As you can see from http://jsfiddle.net/JYHh2/ I'm going crazy from yesterday to make me look the bar, but unfortunately nothing comes out ....

Help me .....

Answer (score 0):

Your data returns string as y values, instead of number. I.e `parseFloat(24.00).toFixed(2)`, is incorrect, because returns `"24.00"` not `24.00`

You can use something like this:

```
parseFloat(parseFloat(24.00).toFixed(2));
```